AWS SDK endpointOverride truncating on create topic calls. (AWS SDK V2 Java)
I am trying to create a topic. (using an emulator instead of real SNS) . As part of this in the SNSClient declaration i ensure the endpointOverride is pointing to my emulator endpoint. The client creation looks fine. But when i try to create a topic, it truncates the url to http://localhost:8080 which makes my code fail. Any inputs why this is happening.
The same logic works fine for SQS. But fails here.
    SnsClient snsClient = SnsClient.builder()
            .region(Region.US_EAST_1) // Specify the region (not used in emulator but required)
            .endpointOverride(URI.create("http://localhost:8080/emulator/sns")) // Full emulator URL
            .httpClient(ApacheHttpClient.create()) // Use the Apache HTTP client
            .overrideConfiguration(ClientOverrideConfiguration.builder()
                .retryPolicy(RetryPolicy.none()) // Disable retries for local development
                .addExecutionInterceptor(new LoggingInterceptor()) // Add the logging interceptor
                .build())
            .build();

    // Create a topic request
    CreateTopicRequest topicRequest = CreateTopicRequest.builder()
            .name("my-topic")
            .build();

    // Call the emulator's create topic method
    CreateTopicResponse topicResponse = snsClient.createTopic(topicRequest);
    System.out.println("Created Topic ARN: " + topicResponse.topicArn());

